# Improving performance of importing big chunks of .xls data to a main .xls

Tags: excel, vba, xls

Is there a way to improve performance of importing big chunks of .xls data to a main .xls?

My code to import data:

Applications at start (and reversing at the end):

```vb
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
SaveChanges = False
```

Import code:

```vb
Workbooks.OpenXML (filePath & "chunkOfData001.xls")
Set WBtemp = ActiveWorkbook
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
Selection.Copy
WBmain.Activate
Sheets("ImportedChunkOfData").Activate
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
WBtemp.Close
```

---

I followed user GWD's tip and got a really great result.

Here is the code now. Can it be pushed further?

I kept Applications

Import code (relevant lines):

```vb
Dim WBmontagem As Workbook
Dim WBsap As Workbook
Dim v As Variant

Set WBmain = ActiveWorkbook

Set WBtemp = Workbooks.OpenXML(filePath & "chunkOfData.xls")
v = WBtemp.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:I150000").Value
WBmain.Sheets("ImportedChunkOfData").Range("A1").Value = v
WBtemp.Close
```

Comment: This might help you: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999/12287457).

Comment: you really helped me. but i wonder if i can push harder

Comment: That's likely about as fast as it can go, unless you can get some speedup by (eg) moving files to a faster drive, since opening the file is likely the slowest part of the process.